# Intellij isn't updating resources of my Google App Engine project automatically

Tags: java, google-app-engine, intellij-idea

When I make a change to a javascript or jsp file while my app is running, I have to click the debug menu and choose Update resources to get the change to show up in the browser.

In my debug configuration, I checked the box "Update resources on frame deactivation" which is supposed to make the update automatic, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This bug will be fixed in next IDEA 10.x update, thank you for reporting.

As a workaround you can use Ctrl+F10 shortcut to invoke 'Update' dialog, select 'Update resources' item and check 'Don't ask again' option. After that Ctrl+F10 will update resources immediately.

Comment: `Update resources` works well, but `Update classes and resources` doesn't work.